# condition property in Ant

Tags: ant

Here's what the manual says about "condition":

> Sets a property if a certain condition holds true. If the condition
>   holds true, the property value is set to true by default; otherwise,
>   the property is not set. You can set the value to something other than
>   the default by specifying the value attribute

What I try:

```
<echo message="${a}" />
<condition property="a">
    <isfalse value="test" />
</condition>
<echo message="${a}" />
```

My reasoning:

if property "a" isfalse then 
   set the value of "a" to "test"

The result that is echoed is:

```
[echo] ${a}
[echo] true
```

The property is set to "true" because it was false, but what is the purpose of "value" then?

thank you

Chris

Answer (score 5):

Ant properties are immutable - once set they cannot be changed. So you can't *modify* the value of "a" but you could set a different property conditionally. For the following slight modification of your problem statement:

> if property "a" is false then set the value of *b* to "test"

you could use

```
<condition property="b" value="test">
  <isfalse value="${a}"/>
</condition>
```

The `condition` tag's property attribute is the property you're setting, and its value attribute is the value to set it *to* if the condition succeeds. The value you're *testing* is the value attribute on the `isfalse`.